# How to retrieve data from CRM 2011 by using webservice and SSIS

Tags: web-services, ssis, dynamics-crm-2011

Goal:
Retrieve data from Dynamics CRM 2011 to my database from SQL server R2  by using webservice through integration services (SSIS). Webservice needed to be located inside of SSIS. Gonna use the data for data warehouse.

Problem:
How do I do it?

Comment: can you elaborate that: "Webservice needed to be located inside of SSIS." first of all, why webservice? why not connect to the db directly?

Comment: @Diego One does not look at Dynamics table directly, on that path madness lies. Which is a similar story to using Siebel, direct table access is highly frowned upon. Everything needs to be a webservice and painfully slow at that. FullmetalBoy, there are plenty of articles on the topic but it generally boils down to using a script component as source/destination or buying/building a custom component.

Comment: @billinkc Reading directly from the CRM database is fully supported and depending on the OP exact needs many well be the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We only write to Dynamics so I can't address the specific method name but the general idea below should get you started.

### Assumptions

Two variables have been defined in your package and they are passed to the script component as ReadOnlyVariables: `CrmOrganizationName`, `CrmWebServiceUrl`.

A script component has been added to the dataflow as a Source component. On the Inputs and Outputs tab, an appropriate number of columns have been added to `Output 0` (or whatever you define your output collection as) with appropriate data types.

Inside the script, add a web reference to your CRM instance. This code assumes it's called `CrmSdk`.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
// web reference
using CrmSdk;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{

    public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
        // Get a reference to the CRM SDK
        CrmSdk.CrmService CrmService = new CrmSdk.CrmService();

        // An Authentication Token is required because CRM requires an OrganizationName
        // to identify the Organization to be used
        CrmSdk.CrmAuthenticationToken token = new CrmSdk.CrmAuthenticationToken();
        token.AuthenticationType = 0;
        token.OrganizationName = this.Variables.CrmOrganizationName;
        CrmService.CrmAuthenticationTokenValue = token;

        // Use default credentials
        CrmService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        // Get the web service url from the config file
        CrmService.Url = this.Variables.CrmWebServiceUrl;

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // This code is approximate 
        // Use the appropriate service call to get retrieve
        // data and then enumerate through it. For each
        // row encountered, call the AddRow() method for
        // your buffer and then populate fields. Be wary
        // of NULLs
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        foreach (CrmSdk.entity person in CrmService.Get())
        {
            Output0Buffer.AddRow();
            Output0Buffer.FirstName = person.FirstName;
            Output0Buffer.LastName = person.LastName;
        }
    }
}
```

### Caveats

There is no error handling, checks for nulls or anything elegant. The service should probably have been defined with the `using` statement, etc, etc, etc. It should provide an appropriate starting point for understanding how to consume a web service and load data into the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for your requirement is to use a third-party library for SSIS. The commercial [COZYROC SSIS+](http://www.cozyroc.com/) library includes Dynamics CRM adapters, which support all deployment models: Premise, Live, Hosted, Federation, Office 365.